# Connect Salesforce and Facebook

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, facebook

I follow the guide: Getting Started with the Force.com Toolkit for Facebook, Version 3.0, but when I click my link site: http://facebookdemonstration-developer-edition.eu6.force.com/demo, I have this screen
[image]

When I click login, the autentication starts, and when it's ended, this page is shown:
 [image]

How can I solve this issue? My intent is to do this example and after build a visualforce page where I can build one post and put it on my  Company's facebook page directly within Salesforce, is it possible?